# Screen type issue on Android Kindle Fire vs Kindle like emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, kindle, kindle-fire

I am trying to create a emulator for Kindle Fire.

```
    public int  ScreenType(Context context){
            return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                    & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK);
    }
```

When I try to get screen type using above function will return Screen type as SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE on actual kindle device, which is correct according to this [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing).

But When I try on emulator using same screen specs am getting screen type as SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE

Specs used for emulator:
Resolution : 1024 x 600 pixels,
LCD density : 160 dpi